# Office 365 online from Unix working only with MTU <= 1400

Tags: networking

First of all --- I really didn't know where to post this question: askubuntu, unix, superuser... I am posting this one here because the only cases I have seen are on Ubuntu and I have a report for Arch... so trying to get the common denominator.

If I try out of the box to connect to `portal.office.com` (and enter a valid user/password), from my Ubuntu 14.04 workstation at work, the connection just sits there forever.

But if I reduce the MTU of the active internet interface (for example `sudo ifconfig eth0 MTU 1400`) to anything less or equal 1400, then the connection automagically works.

This does *not* happen when I connect from home with the same system.

What can cause this behavior? An intermediate router? Notice that no other application/web site has any problem with the default MTU of 1500.

(I think [this](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/18791.aspx) could be related, and it was the hint to try lowering MTU, but I still have no idea about what's happening, and this peeves me).

Comment: ...and the downvote is for... (I don't mind --- would like to know the reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that this is probably due to something blocking ICMP packets of types 3 and 4 from O365 back to your client PC. These packet types report on packet fragmentation across network links. I would have expected these to be classed as "related" packets for a connection and so permitted as part of a TCP conversation, but perhaps not.

If you have a firewall on your client PC it might be worth disabling temporarily (if safe to do so) or accepting inbound ICMP type 3 and 4 packets:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 4 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 3 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Potentially useful reading:

- [Path MTU Discovery and Filtering ICMP](http://www.znep.com/%7Emarcs/mtu/)
- [RFC 1191](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1191)
- [Path MTU Discovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery)

Of course, this may not help if your edge router is blocking them too.

Comment: I have no firewall on my workstation... but I'll pass this answer to the sysadms here and check. Thanks.

Comment: They changed/reconfigured the internal hubs and now it works at MTU 1500 --- I am not sure is directly related, but could be. Thanks!

Comment: Many cloud services use pretty complex NAT/VPN solutions, especially if they are designed to (optionally) allow more privileged access from customer's internal on-site networks than from general public Internet. Those solutions may decrease the MTU the cloud services may be able to accept. As a result, allowing Path MTU Discovery using ICMP types 3 and 4 becomes more important as cloud services become more common.